# Tool (filter) to convert HTML5 into Polyglot Markup?

Tags: html, xml

**Context**: My *HTML5 documents* don’t need JavaScript, animations, forms …. They are "only content". So, it can be filtered about these kind of representations, need only *some subset/constraints* of the "full-HTML5 representation". A good way to express this situation (and other broader ones!) is to say "my documents can be expressed with the *Polyglot Markup* constraints".

**Is there a tool that transforms (or filters losing spurious information) "any HTML5" into [Polyglot XHTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot)?**

Preferably a tool based on extensions for DOM (or XSLT or XQuery).

---

**PS:**

- The [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/) is the most reliable tool for validation... Perhaps some filters can be developed from `validator.nu` infrastructure. Some old (2011's) XSLTs, like [polyglototron.sch](http://web-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/polyglototron/polyglototron.sch) and  [polyglot-xhtml5.xsd](http://www.xmlplease.com/polyglot-xhtml5.xsd), was developed as open source, but no enhances or updates was noticed.
- This question is a complement to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28455886/287948), and a "next step" for [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17188/12499).